# 容量制約付き配送計画問題（CVRP）の定式化とpythonプログラムについて

Tags: python

容量制約付き配送計画問題（capacitated vehicle routing problem, CVRP）に関して、以下のURLを参考にして定式化およびpythonでのシミュレーションを試みました。

参考文献：配送計画問題をpythonで最適化する
URL:https://www.letsopt.com/entry/2020/08/30/180258
作成日：2020/8/30
作成者：cresselia2012

しかし、試みる過程で、以下のMTZ制約に関する制約式とpythonのプログラムがなぜ一致しているのか理解できませんでした。
参考にさせていただいたURL内のpythonのプログラム、特にMTZ制約が正しい理由をご教授いただけますと大変ありがたいです。

理解できなかった理由としては2点あります。

1. 参考文献に記載されている本来のMTZ制約の制約式ではu[j]とdemand[j]に入力される顧客jは同様のはずですが、参考文献に記載されているpythonのプログラムではu[j-1]とdemand[j]と記述されており、一見異なる顧客を入力しているように思えます。

[image: [参考文献で使用されている定式化]]

```
### MTZ制約
for i in range(1,num_nodes):
    for j in range(1,num_nodes):
        if i != j and demand[i] + demand[j] <= capacity:
            problem += u[i-1] - u[j-1] + capacity * x[i][j] <= capacity - demand[j]
```

2. 参考文献に記載されている変数u[i]の入力iは0を含まないと定義されています。
   しかし、MTZ制約に関するpythonのプログラムではi=1のとき、u[0]が生み出されてしまい、矛盾が起きてしまうのかなと疑問に思いました。

```
## 変数を定義
u = [ pulp.LpVariable( 'u_{}'.format( i ), demand[i], capacity, cat="Integer" ) \
        for i in range(1,num_nodes) ]

### MTZ制約
for i in range(1,num_nodes):
    for j in range(1,num_nodes):
        if i != j and demand[i] + demand[j] <= capacity:
            problem += u[i-1] - u[j-1] + capacity * x[i][j] <= capacity - demand[j]
```

ちなみに、以下のように本来のMTZ制約の制約式のままでpythonのプログラムを記述して、シミュレーションをしたところ、

```
for i in range(1,num_nodes):
    for j in range(1,num_nodes):
        if i != j and demand[i] + demand[j] <= capacity:
            problem += u[i] - u[j] + capacity * x[i][j] <= capacity - demand[j]
```

結果としては以下のようなエラーが起き、プログラムが正しくないことがわかりました。
u[i-1] - u[j-1]をu[i] - u[j]に変更したことでエラーが起こったのは明らかなのですが、具体的な原因はわかりませんでした。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Control-PC\Documents\easy_vrp5_compver.py", line 62, in <module>
    problem += u[i] - u[j] + capacity * x[i][j] <= capacity - demand[j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

最後に私がURLを参考にして記述したpythonのプログラムを記載させていただきます。
以下のプログラムのMTZ制約は参考文献と同様のプログラムを使用しており、シミュレーションを行うとエラーは起きません。

```
import math

def makeCVRP():
    num_nodes = 7
    capacity = 30
    demand = [ 0, 9, 11, 13, 7,\
               19, 17 ]
    coordinate = []
    coordinate.append( ( 190, 3 ) )
    coordinate.append( ( 98, 184 ) )
    coordinate.append( ( 5, 42 )  )
    coordinate.append( ( 117, 89 )  )
    coordinate.append( ( 61, 162 ) )
    coordinate.append( ( 9, 97 )  )
    coordinate.append( ( 80, 15 ) )
    def computeDistance( c1, c2 ):
        return math.sqrt( pow( c2[0] - c1[0], 2 ) + pow( c2[1] - c1[1], 2 ) )
    distance = [ [ round(computeDistance( c1, c2 )) for c1 in coordinate ] \
                    for c2 in coordinate ]
    return num_nodes, capacity, demand, distance, coordinate

# make problem
num_nodes, capacity, demand, distance, coordinate = makeCVRP()

import pulp


# 最適化問題を定義
problem = pulp.LpProblem( "CVRP", pulp.LpMinimize )

## 変数を定義
x = [ [ pulp.LpVariable( 'x_{}_{}'.format( i, j ), cat="Binary" ) \
        if i != j else None for j in range(num_nodes) ] \
        for i in range(num_nodes) ]
u = [ pulp.LpVariable( 'u_{}'.format( i ), demand[i], capacity, cat="Integer" ) \
        for i in range(1,num_nodes) ]
num_vehicle= [ pulp.LpVariable( 'num_vehicle', 1, num_nodes, cat="Integer" ) ]

## 最小化したい関数を定義
problem += pulp.lpSum( distance[i][j] * x[i][j] for i in range(num_nodes) \
                        for j in range(num_nodes) if i != j )

## 制約条件を定義
### \sum x_ij = 1
for j in range(1,num_nodes):
    problem += pulp.lpSum( x[i][j] for i in range(num_nodes) if i != j ) == 1

for i in range(1,num_nodes):
    problem += pulp.lpSum( x[i][j] for j in range(num_nodes) if i != j ) == 1

### \sum x_0j = |K|
problem += pulp.lpSum(x[0][j] for j in range(1,num_nodes)) == num_vehicle

### MTZ制約
for i in range(1,num_nodes):
    for j in range(1,num_nodes):
        if i != j:
            problem += u[i-1] - u[j-1] + capacity * x[i][j] <= capacity - demand[j]

# solve
result = problem.solve(pulp.CPLEX_CMD())

print("objective value = {}".format(pulp.value(problem.objective)))


# pulp（CBC）の結果から辺を定義
edges = [ ( i, j ) for i in range(num_nodes) for j in range(num_nodes)
            if i != j and pulp.value(x[i][j]) == 1 ]
            

# edgesから経路を取得
paths = []
for i,j in edges:
    if i == 0:
        path = [ i, j ]
        while path[-1] != 0:
            for v, u in edges:
                if v == path[-1]:
                    path.append(u)
                    break
        paths.append(path)

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 有向グラフの作成
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from( edges )

color = [ "r", "g", "y", "m", "c" ]
edge_color = []

# 経路毎に色をセット
for i,j in G.edges:
    for t,path in enumerate(paths):
        if i in path and j in path:
            edge_color.append( color[t] )
            break
assert len(edges) == len(edge_color)

# グラフの描画
pos = { i : coordinate[i] for i in range(num_nodes) }

fig = plt.figure()
nx.draw_networkx( G, pos, edge_color=edge_color, alpha=0.5)

# 画像を保存
plt.axis("off")
fig.savefig("test.png")

print(plt.show())
```

初めての質問であり、質問の仕方が間違っていたら申し訳ありません。
何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

大変有難いことに知見のある方からご教授いただきました。
理解できていなかった原因を単刀直入に申し上げますと、私のpythonの基礎的な知識不足でした。(そのため専門性は必要ありませんでした。)

以下にご教授いただいた内容を段階的に記載いたします。

step1:
uとdのpython内の定義より、uの添字0の場所(uの配列内の0番目)にu[1]の値が入っており、またdの添字1の場所(dの配列内の1番目)にd[1]の値が入っている。
step2:
よって、u[1]の値とd[1]の値を対応させるためには、uの添字0の場所(uの配列内の0番目)からu[1]の値を、dの添字1の場所からd[1]の値を取り出す必要がある。
step3:
そのため、事前に定式化したMTZ制約を記述した際はu[i] - u[j] + capacity * x[i][j] <= capacity - demand[j]であったが、
今回の場合(uとdのpython内の定義的に)、事前に定式化したMTZ制約と同様の意味を持つMTZ制約をpythonで記述するには、uの添字内を-1し、u[i-1] - u[j-1] + capacity * x[i][j] <= capacity - demand[j]と記述する必要がある。

（例えばj=1をpythonのプログラムに入れてみると、uの添字0の場所から変数u[1]を、dの添字1の場所から変数d[1]を取り出すことができ、u[j-1]とdemand[j]が対応していることがわかる。）

最後に、長い質問文をお読み下さりましたユーザー様、ご教授下さりました回答者様に、御礼申し上げます。